# Look for keywords in a string in JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, substring, cycle, text-search

I have an input field where I expect users to type text that contains 1 of many keywords that will trigger different audio files depending on the keyword. (I know that's not really smart from UX point of view but that's just a mockup/demo of a virtual assistant).

I'm using this code but I feel I can do much better, can you suggest some alternatives?

```
    keyword1 = "music";
    keyword2 = "news";
    keyword3 = "weather";
    keyword4 = "cooking";
    keyword5 = "pasta";
    keyword6 = "tech";

    if(text.search(keyword1)!=-1) {
      audio.src = a_music;
      audio.play();
    } else if(text.search(keyword2)!=-1){
      audio.src = a_news;
      audio.play();
    } 
   [...]
  }
```

Comment: Do a key->value pair array and loop the array. It would be quite nice to actually have a fiddle to give you an example, it's just pure theory here (besides, as long as the problem is solved already it may result in being off topic here).

Answer (score 5):

You could create an object with the keyword as `key` and the file url as `value` and then iterate over the keys to check if the text matches a keyword.

```js
const config = { 
  'music': 'musicUrl',
  'news': 'newsUrl',
  'weather': 'weatherUrl',
  'cooking': 'cookingUrl',
  'pasta': 'pastaUrl',
  'tech': 'techUrl'
};

function match(input, obj) {
  var matched = Object.keys(obj).find(key => input.toLowerCase().search(key) > -1);
  return obj[matched] || null;
}

console.log(match('cats weather dogs', config));
console.log(match('cats tech dogs', config));
console.log(match('cats dogs', config));
```

Comment: Pretty good one here, I would only add a `toLowerCase` and eventually check whether the matched key exists in the config.

Comment: Good point, added it. My match function was intended to return `undefined` if nothing was found. But changed it to return `null` if nothing was found.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an array of keywords instead of one different variable per word. Then it's a piece of cake :

```js
const keywords = ["music","news","weather","cooking","pasta","tech"]

const text = "let's play some music"

if( keywords.some(keyword => text.includes(keyword) )) {
    console.log("Found")
      // audio.src = a_music;
      // audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex here seems a nice approach to me

```js
let keywords = {
  music: 'musicSample',
  news: 'newsSample',
  weather: 'weatherSample',
  cooking: 'cookingSample',
  pasta: 'pastaSample',
  tech: 'techSample'
}

function searchKeywords (text) {
  let keys = Object.keys(keywords)
  let re = new RegExp('(' + keys.join('|') + ')', 'g')
  
  return text.toLowerCase().match(re)
}

console.log(searchKeywords('I love music and tech'))

// Play the first encountered word or queue every word to play consecutively what you found
console.log(searchKeywords('Mama is cooking some pasta')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an array?

```
var array = ["music", "news", "weather", "cooking", "pasta", "tech"];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(text.includes(array[i])){
    //do something with i
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should break your `for` loop when the text is found, otherwise it will uselessly process all the remaining words

Comment: True, added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of searching for keywords in a list of strings that allows for ambiguous order of present keywords.

```
var keywords = [
    'music',
    // 'news',
    // 'weather',
    // 'cooking',
    // 'pasta',
    'tech',
]

var source = [
    "Create a database and tables",
    "What is up with singing",
    "Why is it cold outside",
    "What time is it",
    "How can I set up an appointment",
    "How to make you're own music",
    "Combining music and technology",
]

function search(keywords, source) {
    var re = new RegExp('(' + keywords.join('|') + ')', 'g')
    var results = []
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        const text = source[i];
        var result = text.toLowerCase().match(re)
        if (result != null || result != null) {
            results.push(text)
        }
    }
    return results
}

var results = search(keywords, source)

console.log(results)
```